# C : testing stack size

Tags: c, memory, size, stack-overflow

For educational purposes, I trying to generate a segmentation fault for stack exeeding size. After recovering the stack size with `ulimits -s` (telling me that the maximum dimensions is 8192 kB), I tried the following  minimal code:

```
int main()
{    
    char v[1024*8192];
    return 0;
}
```

Effectively, executing it after `gcc file.c -O0` it raises a segmentation fault. However, it returns seg. fault also with a smaller size, e.g., `1024*8190`. I can think that a part of the stack is reserved with values needed for the execution. But, curiously, if I give value as `1024*8184` or similar and execute the resulting program several times, it raises seg.fault sometimes yes and sometimes no. If the stack occupation by the program is the same, why sometimes it raises segmentation fault and other times no?

UPDATE: as requested, the used code is exactly what I have written.

gcc version is gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)

the used compile command is `gcc file.c -O0`

Comment: Update your code to provide a [mre]. In this case, this means the **exact** code that shows the behavior you are asking about, the code that sometimes generates a segment fault and sometimes does not, not a vague description such as “or similar,” and it also means stating the operating system you are executing on, including its version number, the compiler you are compiling with, including its version number, and the complete command(s) used to compile and build, showing all the switches used.

Comment: ASLR — Address-Space Layout Randomization?  The environment variables and the program's command line arguments also go into the space allocated (even when you ignore them).  You're playing with 'undefined behaviour' and the results you get from doing so are also undefined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I thought about that too, but there ought to be inaccessible zones guarding the stack, and they ought to move with ASLR, so a simple stack overflow by a few bytes should not show varying behavior. OP’s `char [1024*8184]` alone would fit inside the stack with a couple of 4 KiB pages to spare. So how did that plus the minimal stuff on the stack from `start` and `main` manage to get an access beyond the guard zones into someplace that would be affected by ASLR?

Comment: I am figuring macOS because it has an 8 MiB default stack. If OP tried this on a Windows or Linux system, both their `1024*8192` and `1024*8184` cases would far exceed the default stack, so those two cases typically would behave similarly, not differently as OP reports.

Comment: Maybe "better" (for suitable definition of "better") `char v[whatever] = {0};` or `char v[whatever]; v[whatever - 1] = 0;`??

Comment: @EricPostpischil — AFAIK, desktop/server versions of Linux normally default to an 8 MiB stack (but I could easily believe defaults are different for embedded Linux systems).  TTBOMK, Windows defaults to a 1 MiB stack; I agree with you there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) says the GNU `ld` defaults to 2 MiB. (Well, it says “2Mb”, but 250,000 bytes seems rather small, so I presume that is crappy use of notation for 2 mebibytes, not 2 megabits.)